# clase robot intento generar combinacion tecla ALT + I para activar un boton

Tags: java

Hola gente como estan?

Estoy realizando un proyecto que es un juego educativo.
El juego tiene la pantalla de login (JFrame) y una vez identificado el usuario pasa a la pantalla principal(JFrame) donde se puede gestionar su perfil o jugar.

Tengo una clase Sistemas, donde defino todas las constantes de este.
Cree en dicha clase una contante TESTING que indica que el programa esta en modo testing, lo que hace es saltearse el login ingresando con un usuario definido previamente.

Con esto me evito cuando estoy testeando funcionalidad tener que digitar usuario y clave y entrar.

Para ello tengo en el jPanel del login tes componentes
jT_usuario
jP_password
jB_confirmarLogin con el atributo mnemonic con el valor "i"

Cuando esta en modo testing colo en los componentes jT_usuario y jP_password los valores que tengo en dos constantes string dentro de la clase sistema

Instancie la Clase Robot para hacer un keypresed y keyreleased.
al ejecutarlo no da error sin embargo no responde el boton y no encuentro solucion.
Alguien me puede dar una mano?
Desde ya muchas gracias

aqui el codigo

````
try {
tecla = new Robot();
tecla.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
tecla.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
tecla.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
tecla.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
} catch (Exception failed) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fallo Intalización de Robot: " + failed,"atencion",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, el tema no es que cuando el robot mandaba la secuencia de teclas no esta instanciado el jFrame de la clase login.
Entonces lo coloque en el metodo onfocusgained del jButton.